# Adding View programmatically

Tags: android, view, programmatically-created

I am constructing a View through some methods and at the end I am getting a View object which I then add to a LinearLayout. The problem isn't in the last class before I add it to the Linearlayout I want to add another view programmatically. When I try this I don't get any error but the view is somehow invisible.
Here is my code:

```
View newView = new ListItemView().getView(viewList.get(i));

if (AppData.postDimRead) {
    if (dimList.contains(viewList.get(i))) {
         try {
               Log.e("found", "dimView");
               View viewMask = new View(AppData.context);
               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams maskParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
               viewMask.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
               RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) newView.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
               rootView.addView(viewMask, maskParams);
               rootView.requestLayout();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
 }

layout.addView(newView);
layout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Add layout.invalidate() after layout.requestLayout(); for layout refreshing

Comment: That didn't worked for me the View ist still invisible